# Linear Layout does not fill the whole screen

Tags: android, xml, layout, fragment

**Why the linear layout does not fill the whole screen?**

As you can see I am using match parent in the linear layout.
If I delete the Scrollbar nothing changes. The button is not at the bottom of the screen.

**main_activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context="com.sarahp.demo.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout                                 ----------> HERE
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_demo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="@string/demo"
                android:textSize="42dp"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container_a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/transparent"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

F A is the fragment part.
[image]

Comment: Try to give the fragment_container_a, height = 0 and weight = 1

Comment: there is still  a space at the bottom

Comment: how do you want your layout ?

Answer (score 2):

> Give `android:fillViewport="true"` to your ScrollView.

Your xml will looks like below. **Main_Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Test Demo"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/border_image">
             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="100dp"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="Test text Fragement1" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Test text Fragement2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the relative layout

```
<ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout                                
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_demo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="@string/demo"
                android:textSize="42dp"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container_a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/transparent"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```